# Why this dynamodb query failed with 'Requested resource not found'?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have doubled checked that the item exists in the dynamodb table. `id` is the default hash key.

[image]

I want to retrieve the content by using the `main` function in this code:

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2 import table

table='doc'
region='us-west-2'
aws_access_key_id='YYY'
aws_secret_access_key='XXX'

def get_db_conn():
  return boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(
            region,
            aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

def get_table():
  return table.Table(table, get_db_conn())

def main():
  tbl = get_table()
  doc = tbl.get_item(id='4d7a73b6-2121-46c8-8fc2-54cd4ceb2a30')
  print doc.keys()
```

However I get this exception instead:

```
  File "scripts/support/find_doc.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "scripts/support/find_doc.py", line 33, in main
    doc = tbl.get_item(id='4d7a73b6-2121-46c8-8fc2-54cd4ceb2a30')
  File "/Users/antkong/project-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 504, in get_item
    consistent_read=consistent
  File "/Users/antkong/project-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 1065, in get_item
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "/Users/antkong/project-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2731, in make_request
    retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
  File "/Users/antkong/project-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 953, in _mexe
    status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
  File "/Users/antkong/project-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2774, in _retry_handler
    data)
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'Requested resource not found', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ResourceNotFoundException'}
```

Why I am getting this error message?

I am using `boto` version 2.34

Comment: What region are you looking at in the AWS console?

Comment: us-west-2. See variable `region` in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
def get_table():
  return table.Table(table, get_db_conn())
```

It should be

```
def get_table():
  return table.Table(table, connection=get_db_conn())
```

Note the `connection` named parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you have a range key you have to specify in the get_item, like so:

```
get_item(timestamp=Decimal('1444232509'), id='HASH_SHA1')
```

Here on my table Packages I have an index (id) and a range key (timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was connecting to the wrong region.

To check your table region, go to overview tab of your table and scroll down to Amazon Resource Name (ARN) field.

My ARN starts with arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:. Here 'us-east-2' is the region I need to pass while initiating the boto3 client.